# How to determine the possible combinations of births from a multiple pregnancy?

Tags: combinatorics

Let $n>1$ be the number of babies in a multiple birth.

How do we determine all the possible combinations resulting from that birth, assuming that only girls or boys can be born, and that any two boys, or any two girls can be either identical or non-identical (which also means, for example that 3 boys can all be identical, 2 can be identical or non can be identical). For example when $n=2$ we have $T = 5$ possibilities:

2 identical boys
2 identical girls
2 non-identical boys
2 non-identical girls
1 boy and 1 girl

What methods are there to determine $T$, given $n$, and also to enumerate the actual combinations, as above.

Comment: To clarify, for $n=5$ for instance  we could have five girls, two of which are identical and the remaining three of which are identical, and this is considered the same outcome as having three identical girls and two identical girls yes?

Comment: Break into cases based on the number of girls, $k$.  Decide how the girls are split into identical / nonidentical groups.  Then do the same for the boys.  We get $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n p(k)p(n-k)$ ways where $p(k)$ is the number of [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) of $k$.  For the case of $n=2$ that is $p(0)p(2)+p(1)p(1)+p(2)p(0)=1\cdot 2 + 1\cdot 1 + 2\cdot 1 = 5$

Comment: @JMoravitz yes, that is correct (though different from 5 identical girls)